# Existence of certain non-commutative finite monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Is there a finite monoid with two elements $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = e$ but $ba \neq e$?

Comment: Indeed, thanks and sorry.

Comment: The answer to my question is contained in the answer of the other question.